# Webpage redirect for mobile user?

Tags: html, redirect, mobile

I have a website. I want any user that visits my website to be redirected to some different website designed for mobile. For instance: https://m.mywebsite.com

What can I do? I think there is number of way like through which this can be done
1)using javascript
2)using php
3)using meta tag
etc, etc

Can anyone suggest me what to use?

Comment: You can use this plugin to detect device type and os: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js. Based on that you can redirect. Or you can detect the device type using the user agent yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript**

You could use this little script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ) {} else {
    self.location = "m.mywebsite.com";
  }

</script>
```

**PHP**

I didnt try using a serverside solution yet, but it seems like php is capable of retrieving the userAgent information as well. By doing so a user from on a mobile platform would not have to download all the documents associated with your PC-version such as large images.

The PHP solution would look similar to the javascript attempt and would use

```
header("location: m.mywebsite.com");
```

inststead of

```
self.location = "m.mywebsite.com";
```

see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes can you using javascript for check width of screen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

if you want to use sub domain lik this m.domainname.com , create sub domain and put your template

more

[Redirect Mobile Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/)

[Detecting and Redirecting Mobile Users](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/detecting-and-redirecting-mobile-users/)