# How do I redirect a desktop call to action that goes to Appstore or Google Play depending on user's device?

Tags: html, qr-code

How do I create a desktop call to action that goes to either (Apple) Appstore or (Android) Google Play depending on the end-user's needs?

I know we can create multi-link QR codes for mobile but is there anything similar for the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for can reside at the URL in the QR code. The embedded URL could link to a webpage that checks user agents and redirects appropriately. If the Safari on iOS user agent is detected, redirect to Apple's App Store. An Android user agent would be redirected to an appropriate app store. I would set all other user agents to go to a product page with links to both stores.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528547/webpage-redirect-for-mobile-user) could be a nice example!